# When (not how) to use small caps

Tags: small-caps

As much as I found about how to use small caps, I can't seem to find when and why it should be used. I used to use small caps for names, e.g.

```
... we use a \textsc{Taylor}-approximation to show ...
```

But is that even correct, are there other uses for \textsc?
Furthermore, should I capitalize "approximation" as well? 
I would appreciate some insights on this.

Comment: It's an aesthetic/style thing, unless you are expected to follow some typograpahic conventions. Some European conventions put authors' and editors' names in small caps; some North American legal style guides put the titles of books in small caps. Other people like to use small caps in headings; others like to use them for acronyms; others again for abbreviations. In novels or fiction, sometimes they are used for "shouting" in place of full capitals. When I have complete freedom, I tend only to use them (sometimes) for a certain heading level when there's more than one level in play.

Comment: Acronyms. Centred section titles, for instance. Also headers look much nicer in small caps the uppercase.

Comment: personally I use them for abbreviations. They are not actually read as a word. Those abbreviations need to be written in capitals. Having capitals in the flowing text looks stupid and you can sport them from a mile away. That is what I use small caps for. And I might have used them in the odd chapter style.

Comment: Ok thanks, so you think it is not appropriate for scientists. I should rather just write "Taylor-approximation"?

Comment: I use them for some headings in some documents, sometimes for some abbreviations and for the letters immediately following a lettrine. I also sometimes use them in diagrams because they ensure consistent height/depth in nodes (for people's names, for instance).

Comment: This is really off-topic here. The 'how?' is on topic. The 'when?' or 'why?' is not within the remit of this site.

Comment: Writing surnames in caps and small caps I'd tend to associate with French style more than anything else, in English mostly just acronyms and some titles.

Comment: Ok thanks. Furthermore you are right, this may be off-topic, I don't know how to migrate it.

Comment: Off topic; but a common use is for subheadings.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic. It should be migtated to GraphicDesign, were also questions to typography are answered.